# Matlab: how to rename bulk files if varying length

Tags: matlab, bulk, renaming

I am trying to rename over a thousand files of varying length. For example, my original file names are:

1-1.txt
1-13.txt
12-256.txt
...

I would like these files to appear as follows:

100000-1-1.txt
100000-1-13.txt
100000-12-256.txt
...

I have been trying to use the following script:

```
d = 'directoryname';

names = dir(d);
names = {names(~[names.isdir]).name};

len  = cellfun('length',names);
mLen = max(len);

idx   = len < mLen;
len   = len(idx);
names = names(idx);

for n = 1:numel(names)
    oldname = [d names{n}];
    newname = sprintf('%s%100000-*s',d,mLen, names{n});
    dos(['rename','oldname', 'newname']); % (1)
end
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance for your help!!

Comment: So basically you are trying to rename all `.txt` files?

Comment: what if you do `newname = ['100000-' oldname]`? doesn't that work for you?

Comment: Hi hagubear, unfortunately no. When I try it (meaning I am just replacing "sprintf('%s%100000-*s',d,mLen, names{n})" with "['100000-' oldname]" nothing happens.

Comment: What problem do you have exactly? Do you really want the line `idx   = len < mLen`, i.e. rename only files with length smaller than the maximum?

Comment: Hi Luis, thanks for your question. I am VERY new to coding so this is me trying to define the length of the names (since they vary) but I am definitely not wedded to this method!! If there's a better way to do this, I would love to know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works for you -

```
add_string = '100000-'; %//'# string to be concatenated to all filenames
pattern = fullfile(d,'*.txt') %// we are renaming only .txt files

files_info = dir(pattern)
org_paths = fullfile(d,{files_info.name})
new_paths = fullfile(d,strcat(add_string,{files_info.name}))

if ~isempty(org_paths{1}) %// Make sure we are processing something
    cellfun(@(x1,x2) movefile(x1,x2), org_paths, new_paths); %// rename files
end
```

---

### Edit

```
add_string = '100000-'; %//'# string to be concatenated to all files
pattern = fullfile(d,'*.txt') %// Rename .txt files

files_info = dir(pattern);

f1 = {files_info.name};
org_paths = cellfun(@(S) fullfile(d,S), f1, 'Uniform', 0);

f2 = strcat(add_string,f1);
new_paths = cellfun(@(S) fullfile(d,S), f2, 'Uniform', 0);

if numel(org_paths)>0
    if ~isempty(org_paths{1}) %// Make sure we are processing something
        cellfun(@(x1,x2) movefile(x1,x2), org_paths, new_paths); %// rename all files
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Divakar for your help!! I'm receiving the following error: ??? Undefined function or method 'eq' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

Error in ==> fullfile at 39
      elseif (f(end)==fs) || (part(1)==fs || (bIsPC && (f(end)=='/' ||
      part(1)=='/')) )

Error in ==> FILENAME at 7
new_paths = fullfile(d,strcat(add_string,org_names))

Comment: @LauraLigouri Could you check out the updated code? Also for getting the MATLAB version you can just type - `version` in the Command Window.

Comment: Hi Divakar, thanks! I'll try you code next. Meanwhile the version of MATLAB I'm using is 7.11.0.584 (R2010b).

Comment: Hmmm... I'm still receiving an error: ??? Undefined function or method 'eq' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

Error in ==> fullfile at 39
      elseif (f(end)==fs) || (part(1)==fs || (bIsPC && (f(end)=='/' ||
      part(1)=='/')) )

Error in ==> FILENAME at 6
new_paths = fullfile(d,strcat(add_string,{files_info.name}))

Comment: @LauraLigouri Hmm that mostly looks like a version issue. I am on version 2014a. I have added an Edit section, could you check out that code?

Comment: Interesting code! I'm receiving this error now: ??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in ==> FILENAME at 12
if ~isempty(org_paths{1}) %// Make sure we are processing something

Comment: Hi Divakar, wow, thanks for spending so much time on this!!! Please excuse me if this is my lack of coding knowledge... the script seems to be working (at least no error is taking place) however what I get in the Command Window is pattern = FILEPATH/*.txt and none of the file names are actually changed. Am I supposed to do something else now?

Comment: @LauraLigouri As a quick check, could you do this - `val = exist(d,'dir')`, it must return `val` as `7`. Let me know?

Comment: Hmmm... it says val = 0

Comment: @LauraLigouri So, here's my best guess - If you are on Windows OS, for `d` you might be mistakenly using `/` as the path separator, but you should be using `'\'`, so if you are doing something like `C:/proj/`, then it's wrong. Change all those `'/'`  to `'\'`. Let me know if that's the issue? Also make sure the path actually exists?

Comment: Eureka! / is correct for my operating system however when I went back to check, I noticed I was missing the initial / at the beginning of the path. That did the trick. SO EXCITED!!!! Thank you so much Divakar for all your help! Your code now works like a charm.

Comment: haha @LauraLigouri@ Nice! Well that brings me a sigh of relief! :) Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get what you are doing with `len` and `mLen`, but assuming that's correct, you just need the following changes within the `for` loop:

```
for n = 1:numel(names)
    oldname = [d filesep names{n}]; %// include filesep to build full filename
    newname = sprintf('100000-%s', names{n}); %// prepend '100000-' to names{n}
    %// or replace by the simpler: newname = ['100000-' names{n}];
    dos(['rename' oldname ' ' newname]); % (1) %// oldname and newname are variables
end
```

Comment: Thanks Luis, makes sense but so far nothing seems to be happening.